# Trouble checking a string for numbers in C

Tags: c, string, char

I've checked similar questions posted here on the forum, but none of those answers my question.

I have a string (`char s []`) and I want to 'copy' the numbers in that string to another one (`char n []`).

Here's my attempt at this:

```
   char s[] = "oa323shsh123383.33hbabsa3€"
   int len = strlen(s);
   char n[];
   int k;

   for (k = 0; k <= len; k++){
       if( s[k] >= '0' || s[k] <= '9') {
           n[k] = s[k] - 48;
       }
   }
```

However this is wrong, because it doesn't print out anything. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Are you sure this `char n[];` compiles?

Comment: you don't allocate space for 'n', and moreover, what are you really trying to do? the 'slots' that don't have numerals remains unassigned, and those that do get something that is not printable.

Comment: no it doesn't, but if i just give it a dimension,  which is a fixed one in this case, so it compiles fine. but i left it blank because that's not the issue here, i think the problem is the if condition in the for loop...

Comment: @sp2danny i'm trying to take the string 's', and copy only the numbers in that string to another string called n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use && in your IF.

Allocate your array n. Easy way is to declare n as

```
char n[] = char[len+1];
```

Use another variable to count the number being added to n, otherwise you will have n being:

```
"..323....123383" etc
```

Should end up with something like

```
char s[] = "oa323shsh123383.33hbabsa3€"
int len = strlen(s);
char n[] = char[len+1];
int k, j=0;

for (k = 0; k <= len; k++){

    if( s[k] >= '0' && s[k] <= '9') {
        n[j] = s[k] - 48;
        n[j+1] = '\0';
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out!

Comment: Then set the answer as the correct one, if you wouldn't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[] = "oa323shsh123383.33hbabsa3€";
int len = strlen(s);
char* n = (char*) malloc(len+1);
int i,j=0;

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    if( s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        n[j++] = s[i];
}
n[j]=0;
```

`n` is now a printable string
dont forget to `free` it when you are done.